# Http Cache in Symfony2

Tags: php, http, symfony, caching

I have read the Symfony2 docs about Http Cache, but have not followed it properly. Can anyone suggest any other working example/link/resource/mini-project of Http Caching in Symfony2 with working code and how it works with explanation????

Answer (score 2):

Take a look of this bundle how implement "http cache"

> https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSHttpCacheBundle
>   http://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but can you suggest any other resource/link which is without using a third party bundle???

Comment: take a look of this : http://fr.slideshare.net/odino/be-lazy-be-esi-http-caching-and-symfony2-phpday-2011

Comment: I found a few more links :- https://tracehello.wordpress.com/author/pablobandin/page/8/ , http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://blog.eleven-labs.com/symfony-2-cache-http-esi/&prev=search , https://gist.github.com/nikrou/8d90353d6b8f41070eb0 (http://www.nikrou.net/) , https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.in&sl=fr&u=http://michael.schuh.free.fr/blog/index.php%3Fpost/2013/01/Testons-la-mise-en-cache-HTTP-avec-Symfony2&usg=ALkJrhi4Gn_lW6-LexbhuR5io6ISLuxkUg ,

Comment: https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.in&sl=fr&u=https://github.com/mikachou/test_cache&usg=ALkJrhjl1v8Y8xQYRMsLXPuixD7DHguPWQ